# How to have two v-model directive inside ValidationProvider in VeeValidate?

Tags: html, vue.js, vee-validate

I want to create a custom Date Picker component with Vue version 2 and VeeValidate. I am using vuetify and v-menu component from there: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/ . The problem is that `ValidationProvider` which is responsible for validating fields accepts only one `v-model` inside of it and I have two: one for triggering `v-menu` and second for gathering value to `v-text-field` from `v-date-picker`. When I remove this v-model from v-menu validation works but I cannot close menu after I choose some values in date-picker.

```
<ValidationProvider v-slot="{ validate, errors }">
  <label>...</label>
  <v-menu v-model="menu">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-text-field
        v-bind="attrs"
        :value="formatDate"
        readonly
        v-on="on"
        @input="$emit('input', $event) || validate($event)"
      />
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
      :value="value"
      no-title
      @input="$emit('input', $event) || validate($event)"
      @change="menu = false"
    />
  </v-menu>
  <span
    v-if="errors.length > 0"
  >{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Comment: Can you move the `ValidationProvider` inside of the v-menu component instead? You can still show the error message outside by catching any errors using an `ValidationObserver`.

Comment: How do you catch this error? By name?

Comment: The `ValidationObserver` collects all errors from any nested `ValidationProvider` (and other observers) wrapped within it. Similar to the providers, the observer expsoes these errors through scoped slots, like this `<ValidationObserver v-slot="{ errors }">`.

Comment: Yeah I know how it works but ValidationObserver collects all of the errors from all ValidationProviders so to display it in one specific field I need to get it by its name? index?